# Let $D$ be a domain, $a,b \in \mathbb{C}\setminus D$ and $f(z)=\frac{z-a}{z-b}$. Then there exists a holomorphic branch of the log of $f$ on $D$.

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

Let $D\subset \mathbb{C}$ be a domain and define $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by $f(z)=\frac{z-a}{z-b}$, where $a,b \in \mathbb{C}\setminus D$ are in the same connected component of $\mathbb{C}\setminus D$. I want to show that there exists a holomorphic branch of the logarithm of $f$ on $D$.

I would like to use the following theorem regarding the existence of a holomorphic log:

Let $D$ be a simply connected domain, $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^*$ holomorphic, $z_0\in D$, and $w_0$ a log of $f(z_0)$. Then there exists a unique $g: D \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, a holomorphic function, such that $g$ is a branch of the log of $f$ and such that $g(z_0)=w_0.$

My issue with applying this theorem is that the assumption is that $D$ be simply connected, whereas I would like to prove the above problem where we assume only that $D$ is a domain. My first thought was to take some small enough ball contained in $D$, which is a simply connected domain, and apply the theorem to that small ball to guarantee the existence of a holomorphic branch of the log of $f$ on that simply connected domain. However I'm not sure how I could extend this to be true of the whole of $D$. Does anyone know how I could proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't we try to construct this logarithm, using the *ideas* from the proof of the result that you quote?

Define $g: D \to \mathbb C$ by
$$ g(z) := \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} = \frac{1}{z - a} - \frac{1}{z - b}.$$

Our objective is to construct a holomorphic function $G: D \to \mathbb C$ such that $G' = g$ on $D$. If we succeed, then this $G$ will be a logarithm of $f$. (Check this!)

The idea is to define
$$ G(z) := \int_{\alpha_{z_0 \to z}} g(w) \ dw,$$
where $\alpha_{z_0 \to z}$ is a path in $D$ from some fixed point $z_0 \in D$ to an arbitrary point $z \in D$.

But for this definition to make sense, we need to ensure that our definition is independent of the choice of path $\alpha_{z_0 \to z}$.

If $D$ were simply connected, then this would be a direct consequence of Cauchy's theorem. Unfortunately, $D$ is not necessarily simply connected, so we have to work a little harder.

So suppose that $\alpha_{z_0 \to z}$ and $\alpha'_{z_0 \to z}$ are two different paths in $D$ from $z_0$ to $z$. Let $\gamma$ be the closed loop formed by traversing $\alpha_{z_0 \to z}$ in the forward direction then traversing $\alpha'_{z_0 \to z}$ in the reverse direction.

Then
$$ \int_{\alpha_{z_0 \to z}} g(w) \ dw - \int_{\alpha'_{z_0 \to z}} g(w) \ dw = \oint_{\gamma} g(w) \ dw = 2\pi i \times  (\text{Ind}_\gamma (a) - \text{Ind}_\gamma(b)),$$
where $ \text{Ind}_\gamma (a)$ and $ \text{Ind}_\gamma (b)$ are the [winding numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number#Complex_analysis) of $\gamma$ around $a$ and $b$ respectively.

But $a$ and $b$ are in the same connected component of $\mathbb C \setminus D$, and hence are also in the same connected component of $\mathbb C \setminus \gamma^\star$. Therefore, $ \text{Ind}_\gamma (a)$ is equal to $ \text{Ind}_\gamma (b)$. (See the theorem in the Wikipedia article I linked, or see Rudin Theorem 10.10.)

So
$$ \int_{\alpha_{z_0 \to z}} g(w) \ dw = \int_{\alpha'_{z_0 \to z}} g(w) \ dw, $$
which shows that our definition of $G$ is independent of the choice of path $\alpha_{z_0 \to z}$.

(You also need to prove that our $G$ is holomorphic. I'll leave that to you.)

Comment: This was immensely helpful, I was completely lost on how to address the lack of simple connectivity!